# Escape Sequence in Delphi (#$A)

Tags: delphi

I am getting a string in Delphi XE4 as

'Hello World'#$A'Welcome to Delphi'

What kind of escape character #$A is in Delphi?

I am referring http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Escape_sequences_and_escape_characters & http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:StrStringToEscaped@AnsiString, but did not get any clue?

Comment: It is hexa `0xA` which is `LF` (line feed) char.

Comment: @TLama - So, can I use #10 instead of this?

Comment: Yes, `$A` is a hexa notation of decimal `10`. Before that value is `#` which denotes a char constant.

Comment: @nkp You could, but you aren't a real programmer until you are more at home with hex than decimal!  ;-)

Comment: The other you're likely to encouter is $D$A. This is Carriage Return + Line Feed (CRLF). Which is the more common way of denoting a new line in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is [Unicode Character 'LINE FEED (LF)' (U+000A)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm).

The [Fundamental Syntactic Elements topic in the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Character_Strings) explains what the literal `#$A` means.

Comment: Can you please give me any clue on my this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688941/delphi-xe4-and-reportbuilder-15-tppmemo-field-issue

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea about the subject matter there, outside my area of expertise

Answer (score 2):

`#` is used to specify character using its code. E.g. `#65` is the same as `Chr(65)`, which is capital letter `'A'`.

Now, hexadecimal numbers are specified with prefix `$`, which means that:

```
`#$A` = `#10` = Chr($A) = Chr(10) = LF
```

This is LF (Line Feed) character, which is in your case used to break the text into two lines.