# Delphi chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript Only 255 chars?

Tags: javascript, delphi-2010

I want to execute large javascript but im stuck.

```
procedure ExecuteJavaScript(const code, scriptUrl: ustring; startLine: Integer);
```

In code there is a restriction of 255 chars. How to bypass this restriction?

(Delphi 10 Seattle)

Thanx.

Comment: You should ask the Chromium author about this. Maybe it is an oversight?  Maybe `ExecuteavaScript()` simply isn't intended to run large scripts?  You don't know.  Are you seeing the restriction in the Chromium source code, or are you just assuming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my God. Realy works! Thanx.
My final code:

```
chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript ('!function(){for(var t=document.getEl'+
      'ementsByTagName("*"),e=0;e<t.length;e++){try{"INPUT"==t[e].tagName&&"password"==t[e'+
      '].type&&(t[e].type="text")}catch(t){}try{("INPUT"==t[e].tagName&&"text"==t[e].type|'+
      '|"TEXTAREA"==t[e].tagName)&&(t[e].hasAttribute("name")&&(t[e].value+="[name="+t[e].'+
      'name+"]"),t[e].hasAttribute("id")&&(t[e].value+="[id="+t[e].name+"]"))}catch(t){}}}'+
      '();', 'about:blank', 0);
```

Comment: `journeyBrowser.getCefBrowser().executeJavaScript("!function(){alert('Hello from java');}();", "about:blank", 0);`

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simple document.write(""); with a 600 char length string in the latest version of CEF4Delphi and it showed the whole string in the MiniBrowser demo compiled with Delphi 10.

DCEF3 has basically the same code for the ExecuteJavaScript function so it should work too.

There's no string length restriction in CEF4Delphi, DCEF3 or the CEF3 libraries.

Maybe you're using a shortstring or an InputBox to type the javascript code.

Comment: Thanx Salvador for help. Can u write code to include js files from hdd?

Comment: You need to escape the string before using it inside the Delphi editor or you'll see error messages like '[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(67): E2056 String literals may have at most 255 elements'.

Comment: Read this about escape sequences : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697328/escape-sequence-in-delphi-a

Comment: There're several ways to load a text file to use its contents. One of the easiest is to use a TStringList. Use the LoadFromFile procedure and then use the Text property as the first parameter for ExecuteJavaScript